# I'm getting a "test interstitial" message, and the music is gone — How do I fix this?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

After the last update to TDS, my music is gone. Also, I'm getting a "test interstitial" message when powering on the game. How do I fix these issues?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of this?  I know TDS now has ads when you launch the game that are directly related to TDS gameplay.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same once. I believe it was a placeholder for an ad. It appeared the same as the pop-up ads I've seen when starting up the game.